# Send HTTP Request to a device behind router

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, sockets, websocket, push

I have a device that is connected to a home network behind a router which need to receive a request to activate some function.

The way i do it now is that i have port forwarding set in the router which handles these external requests and forwards them to the device.

One other way to do it as far as i know would be to hold an open socket connection to the server and constantly listen to these messages, but i would try to avoid this because the data transfer happens something like once a day at and constantly keeping an open connection will cost valuable server resources.

I still need to send this data and the device to be triggered at the same moment data is passed to it.

I have also considered pulling for new messages from the device every 5 minutes or so, but that way i am losing the realtime effect.

The need is to write a server that can scale to communicate with at least 10 000 devices like these. Preferably written in something like Ruby on Rails or Node.js.

A request is being sent once a day in average as a small message.

So what is the best option for achieving this? How do i "push" to the device from the server with consideration to scaling in the near future?

**EDIT:**

Consider the device as a on/off switch. The switch can be flipped manually on the actual device or triggered remotely by the server. When triggered manually it will be responsible for propagating the state to the server, when being triggered remotely it is supposed to listen and react for a message from the server that can happen at any time (so the device cannot ping the server for status in intervals, needs to be realtime).

Comment: What kind of device / operating system is the client?

Comment: Its a microcontroller. Supports Http requests, i am not building it but i am pretty sure it can handle sockets, not sure about having libraries for websockets.

Comment: Writing answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use Rails for the data-handling system (storing the messages etc)

I was thinking about this exact thing last night:

1. Rails will create a series of [endpoints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_endpoint)
2. When your "device" wants to communicate, it will have to initiate a request to the endpoints
3. The device will push to the Rails endpoints

---

**Device**

Without knowing what the device is, the way I'd imagine it working is that it will have to be able to initiate a `POST` request (imagine a [Rasberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) sending data) when something happens

If your device is a toothbrush, you'd have to have capabilities (either on chip or externally) for it to connect to the net & send data to your (insert framework) server

---

**Rails**

Rails could handle it like this (this is some of our live analytics system code which works in a similar way):

```
#config/routes.rb
post "/update", to: "messages#create"

#app/controllers/messages_controller.rb
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session    
before_action :authenticate

#Data
def create
    #create message here
end

private

# have to give x a "token" 
def authenticate 
authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
    user = User.exists?(public_key: token)
    @token = token if user
end
end
```

This will create the endpoint:

```
domain.com/update
```

You'll have to send your [authentication token](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Token.html) in the headers, and may need to use [rack-CORS](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) (or another [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) policy manager) to handle the x-domain transactions:

```
#config/application.rb
config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
    allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '/update*', :headers => :any, :methods => :post
    end
end
```

---

**Data**

The Rails stuff is an [MVC application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (which can scale depending on your backend sever resources)

The tricky part will come when you want to integrate the device to the backend. You mention you can support http requests -- the trick will be "how"

> 1. You'll have to integrate some authentication (probably serial number), which will have to be present in your Rails DB
> 2. This will then be sent via the device through the net to your endpoint
> 3. Once you've had the request, Rails can handle it on the server & return a response

So the big question is -- how is your device going to communicate with the server?

---

**Cross Communication**

`Server -> Device` communication is [push technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology):

1. Device will ping "live stream" (via JS in browsers, not sure in others)
2. Server will send data to specific "channels"
3. If Device is subscribed to channel, it will receive update

The question is less about "web socket" technology as it is about ["sub/pub"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern)

In the browser world, you'd basically open a perpetual connection with Javascript. This can be done by either using [SSE's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) (glorified [long-polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling)) or [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)

Both can be accessed by "listening" to events on your channel:

```
#Pusher
channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
  alert('An event was triggered with message: ' + data.message);
});

#SSE's
var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.php");
source.onmessage = function(event) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML + =event.data + "<br>";
};
```

In terms of your device, I would be looking at how often you want to receive data from the server. Of course, *sending* data is an "on-demand" service, but receiving does, as you say, carry an overhead

If you only expected a message every day, I would look at using some sort of `long-polling` technology to look for data every `x` hours; if you need the message immediately, I'd look at integrating a persistent connection with a web socket

---

**Server**

Handling this on the server will come down to how many concurrent connections your server can handle

If you're using AWS, you'll be able to scale relatively simply, but each connection will be classed as "concurrent"

Comment: My thinking was in the same direction when it comes to the device -> Server communication. The device is fully capable of doing what you describe. It is a box connected to the router which transmits RF signals. I am curious about the other way. How will the server push messages to the device behind a router. so Server -> Device. As far as i know the device needs to be the one that has to open the connection otherwise the server cannot reach it.

Comment: If you submit a POST request, the `response` of that request will be directly to the device (like how a browser works). However, if you're wanting to `send` messages from the server, you're going to have to use something like a web socket ([Pusher](http://pusher.com)) technology

Comment: I can write some information about that if you want?

Comment: Yeah i do. Thanks! I can figure out the device -> server, but i don't have experience using web sockets to keep a persistent connection and how that scales in systems that require this amount of connections. and seems like an overhead to keep a live connection for something that needs to be contacted once a day sending it something like 100 bytes of data.

Comment: Yes it will be an overhead, hence why I was writing that it would be beneficial to focus the technology on sending data to the server, and not the other way round. I'll write what I know about websockets for you now